pipeline to copy specific files from ADLS based on names in an Azure SQL Database table using required parameters?
there are 10 files with names like Ex: India, Australia, Africa, South Korea, Afghanistan, Canada, Ireland, USA, Scotland, Oman these files will have some sample data then in azure SQL will have a table with 5 rows containing names from those 10 files like India, South Korea, Canada, USA, Oman we have to create a pipeline in such a way it will read that 5 file names from SQL server table and pass that value store it in a variable or parameter then copies those 5 files from ADLS container and stores it in another container in 5 folders.
I have taken a Lookup activity to retrieve the file names from the SQL table and store them in an array variable. Next, taken a ForEach activity to iterate over each file name in the array. Inside the ForEach loop, used a Get Metadata activity to gather information about the files in the source ADLS container, followed by a Copy activity to copy the files to another ADLS container based on the retrieved file names. But in copydata activity in source it is asking for wildcard path without using wildcard path how to solve this.

As you have all the file names array in a variable from lookup activity, there is no need to use Get meta data activity.
After giving the file names array to ForEach, inside for-loop, use copy activity with dataset parameters.
Create source and target datasets. In the datasets, create parameters for the folder path and file path.
Target dataset:
As you need to copy each file to individual folder, your folder should also be dynamic. So, create parameters for both folder and filename.

Use these in the folder path and file path like below.

Source dataset:
Here, only the file names should be dynamic. So, create parameter for the file name and use it same as above.

NOTE: If source files are in different folders, then first you need to make list of source folder path and filepaths like this[{"folder_path":"folder1/subfolder1","filename":"file1.csv"},...] and use this as for-each input.
Now, give the above datasets as copy activity source and sink inside for-loop. In source, give the current filename from the current iteration like @item().<table_column_name> to the dataset parameter. Here, filename is my table_column_name from the SQL table.

In the target, create the folder name from the file name itself (if file name is file1.csv then folder name will be file1). Give the expression @split(item().filename,'.')[0] and @item().filename to the dataset parameters.

Debug the pipeline and it will give the expected results.

